# php assign 2 variables to form value element

Tags: php

Is there a way to assign 2 variable values to a value in a form:

```
echo "  <input name='Radio1' type='radio' value='$course_id . $date_1'/>$date_1</br>";
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can concatenate them using a "_" or other symbol. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My apologies, I stated the question badly, I'm getting a result but it has the . in between, I tried STEFAN's answer and got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be what you are looking for:

```
echo "  <input name='Radio1' type='radio' value='$course_id$date_1'/>$date_1</br>";
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
echo "  <input name='Radio1' type='radio' value='".$course_id.$date_1."'/>$date_1</br>";
```

Regards,

STEFAN

Comment: More readable would be `<input name="Radio1" type="radio" value="<?php echo $course_id, $date_1 ?>" /><?php echo $date_1 ?></br>`... well, that might be subjective...

Comment: it definitely is, I am not a big fan of PHPs template like usage

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

`echo '<input type="radio" name="Radio1" value="',$course_id,'_',$date_1,'" />',$date_1,'<br />';`

On the receiving page:

```
$parts = explode('_',$_GET['Radio1']);
$course_id = $parts[0];
$date = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This way has the data separated in perhaps a more useful way:

```
<input type="text" name="course[$course_id]" value="$date_1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `printf`

```
$input = "<input name='Radio1' type='radio' value='%s%s'/>%s</br>";
printf ( $input, $course_id, $date_1, $date_1 );
```